# Final enum classes in C++11

Tags: c++, c++11, enums, final

I am just curious whether an enum class can be final or not ... since the compilers are giving me contradictory results.

Consider the code:

```
#include <iostream>

enum class some_enums final : char
{
    a = 'a', 
    b = 'b',
    c = 'c'
};

int main()
{
    some_enums aa = some_enums::a;
    std::cout << "aa=" << static_cast<char>(aa) << std::endl;
}
```

Compiling this with Visual Studio 2015 compiler (http://rextester.com/l/cpp_online_compiler_visual) works... however compiling it with clang (http://rextester.com/l/cpp_online_compiler_clang) gives me an error:

```
source_file.cpp:3:30: error: expected ';' after top level declarator
        enum class some_enums final : char
```

I have seen no traces of final enum classes anywhere in the standard so I give credit to clang ... however why does Visual Studio accept it in this case although it is not mentioned in MSDN (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2dzy4k6e.aspx) ?

Comment: and what effect would `final` have on an enum?

Comment: [enum class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a6cskb49.aspx) documentation doesn't mention it either. I suspect that this is a compiler bug.

Comment: Also note that in C++ a class cannot be inherited from built-in types like `char`.

Comment: @Sergey enum class is different, the underlying type is always an integral type.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `final` specifier is used to signify that a class cannot be inherit from. Since an `enum class` cannot be inherited, the `final` specifier used in your case is useless.

"Stollen" from [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/enum) and also mention in *§7.2/p1 Enumeration declarations [dcl.enum]*
, a `class enum` declaration is of the form:

```
enum-key attr(optional) nested-name-specifier(optional) identifier enum-base(optional) ;
```

- `enum-key`    -   one of `enum`, `enum class` (since C++11), or `enum struct` (since C++11)
- `attr` (C++11)    -   optional sequence of any number of attributes
- `identifier`  -   the name of the enumeration that's being declared. If present, and if this declaration is a re-declaration, it may be preceded by `nested-name-specifier` (since C++11): sequence of names and scope-resolution operators `::`, ending with scope-resolution operator. The name can be omitted only in unscoped enumeration declarations.
- `enum-base` (C++11)   -   colon (:), followed by a `type-specifier-seq` that names an integral type (if it is `cv-qualified`, qualifications are ignored).
- `enumerator-list` -   comma-separated list of enumerator definitions, each of which is either simply an identifier, which becomes the name of the enumerator, or an identifier with an initializer: `identifier = constexpr`. In either case, the identifier can be directly followed by an optional attribute specifier sequence. (since C++17).

Consequently, defining an `enum class` with `final` specifier as:

```
enum class some_enums final : char {
...
};
```

is not a standard form.

Comment: Exactly my thoughts too... I was just curious why MSVS enables it without a mention of syntax error

Comment: @fritzone Probably something got astray in the implementation.